# Implementing font family from resource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF,C#,XAML
and I wanted to implement a new font family.
the font has been downloaded from the internet and it is a file called:
"LiberationMono-Regular.ttf"

I opened a "Font" folder and add the file into it.
I would like to implement this font into a specific style.
I try to implement it does not work for me.

attaching the code I wrote will appreciate your help

Thanks.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="DataFont">LiberationMono-Regular.ttf"</FontFamily>
</Window.Resources>

 <Style TargetType="syncfusion2:GridCell" x:Key="ComCellData">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding COMPort , Converter={StaticResource CVconverters }  }" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BookMarkAndSelectedMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="isBookMarked"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="isSelected"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource DataFont}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the custom font family by its name:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="DataFont">/#Liberation Mono</FontFamily>
```

The above markup assumes that you have added the `LiberationMono-Regular.ttf` to the root of your project and set its `Build Action` to `Resource`.